# Accessing Docker container from non-host device

Tags: docker

Bear with me, I'm new to Docker...

I'm trying to get a Docker environment going on a Red Hat Linux server (7.6) and am having trouble accessing containers from a computer other than the host.

I got Docker installed no problem.  Then, the first container I installed was Portainer and the Portainer Agent:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
docker run -d -p 9001:9001 --name portainer_agent --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes portainer/agent
```

Seems peachy:

```
# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
973a685cfbe1        portainer/portainer   "/portainer"        19 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   portainer
602537dc21ec        portainer/agent       "./agent"           45 hours ago        Up 19 hours         0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp                           portainer_agent
```

And using `# curl http://localhost:9000` connects just fine.  However, the connection gets dropped when attempting to connect from another computer on the same network (in a different subnet, if that matters).  I can connect to the server just fine (I'm managing it via SSH, and even tested netcat on port 9002 for good measure).

The iptables, if this helps:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:etlservicemgr
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:cslistener
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:irdmi

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I've searched around a bit but keep finding conflicting answers (some suggesting that it should just work, and others suggesting that there's a lot more I've got left to learn and configure).  I'm afraid that I'm fumbling in the dark.  I gather that I need a route configured to forward host traffic to the container?  Or an iptables rule?  What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

...Nevermind.

On a lark, I tried connecting to the server from a device that's on-premises; rather than my computer which is connected via VPN.  The on-prem device connected fine.